# Specifying the Group a New Message Should Go to for the Yammer Share Button

Tags: yammer

I am using the Yammer share button (not the api).

I noticed all it does is open a new popup with the url structure as:

https://www.yammer.com/messages/new with these parameters:

`login:     Whether to log the user in or not
status:    Message to include in the post
trk_event: yammer_share (some tracking event)`

However this always defaults to post to "All Company" group, is there a way to post to a specified group?

Maybe pass in the Group Id as a parameter or some other identifier like name?

Thanks,
Greg